# Applet Error Java Print Console

Tags: java, web, applet

Okay, so I have this applet I wrote in eclipse, and it draws a circle, then prints "YEAH" in the console. The first part (drawing the circle) works. However, the program prints nothing to the console.

Any ideas why? Oh, and here's the code, should you need it:

```
 import javax.swing.JApplet;
 import java.awt.*;

 public class Tuna extends JApplet{
  public static void main(String[] args){
      System.out.println("Yeah!");
  }
 final int radius = 25;

  public void paint ( Graphics gr )
  { 
    gr.setColor( Color.white );
    gr.fillRect( 0, 0, 150, 150 );
    gr.setColor( Color.black );

    gr.drawOval( (150/2 - radius), (150/2 - radius), radius*2, radius*2 );
   }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Applets don't use a static `main()` method. Their lifecycle has been given a more-detailed structure of interaction with their container.

Lifecycle interaction with their container, goes thru these four methods:

```
public void init();
public void start();
public void stop();
public void destroy();
```

Plus:

```
public void paint (Graphics gr);
```

Overriding `start()` or `init()`, should do what you want.

Comment: hmm...I put the System.out.println into the public void main and it worked! Pretty sure that's what you asked me to do, so thanks! If not, still thanks.